# Python 3: How can I remove time? I just want the number of days

Tags: python

Right now I have this code. I am intending to write code that calculates the number of days between today and January 1 of this year.

As you can see in the output below, it prints the number of days and the time.

How can I rewrite the code so that it says just '78', not '78 days, 21:04:08.256440'?

```
from datetime import datetime
Now = datetime.now()
StartDate = datetime.strptime(str(Now.year) +'-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
NumberOfDays = (Now - StartDate)

print(NumberOfDays)


#Output: 78 days, 21:04:08.256440
```

Comment: Use `NumberOfDays.days`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working [Fiddle](https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/c8da25e1-ba0f-4323-b935-30238b5e1ff4/?i=true).

As jpp commented on your question you had to use `print(NumberOfDays.days)`.
But be careful, in your solution it return 78 (on the **20/03/2018**) but it is the 79th day (starting from 1).

Another simpler way to do it is : `print(datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday)`

And another even simpler way to do it : `print(Now.strftime('%j'))`

```
from datetime import datetime

Now = datetime.now()
StartDate = datetime.strptime(str(Now.year) +'-01-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
NumberOfDays = (Now - StartDate)

print(NumberOfDays.days)                     # 78
print(datetime.now().timetuple().tm_yday)    # 79
print(Now.strftime('%j'))                    # 079
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import datetime
today = datetime.date.today()
first_day = datetime.date(year=today.year, month=1, day=1)
diff = today - first_day
print(diff)

78 days, 0:00:00
```